# Code Cop App just hangs

Tags: c#, .net, method-interception

I written an test application using a Code Cop, a method interception approach.

However, as soon as I ran my first application I hit a snag whereby the application would fire up and hang with no information as to what was happening.

I had followed the code exactly and was able to run the same code on another machine.

There is no error information being output, it just hangs.

Does anyone know how I may be able to solve or debug this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to contact Ricardo Barbosa at [CodeCop](http://www.getcodecop.com/) who proceeded to help me solve this issue promptly and explaining why this was occurring.

My issue was due to not having the correct CLRJIT.dll on my machine

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework

A Windows update solved the issue.

### What's Happening

When the CodeCop application runs it creates a folder in %temp%/CodeCop and downloads symbol files from Microsoft to calculate method addresses.

The version I had was 4.6.57.0 in my v4.0.30319 framework folder.

For some reason there was no symbol file from the Microsoft public symbol server for this version of the CLRJIT.dll

Running Fiddler while starting the application showed this to be the case.

[image]

After I performed a Windows update I got version 4.6.100.1 of the clrjit.dll the application built and performed as expected.

Thanks to Ricardo for spending the time to solve this issue for me.